# Django Development Server is not accessible from other computer : This Site Cannot be Reached

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access my django dashboard from other computer over the same network through LAN. I have updated the `setting.py` with following lines to access from other computers:

```py
> DEBUG = False
>
> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost','myip']
```

I have also Updated `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` but when i run the server from the any of following command in CMD as well as in the terminal of VSCODE :

```sh
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  
$ python manage.py runserver myip:8000
```

it says ***This Site cannot be reached myip took too long to respond.*** I am able to access my dashboard on my system and it works fine but when i access it from other computer over the same network it says This site cannot be reached. Moreover, few days ago it was accessible from other computers over the same network but now giving this following error:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to access it on your system using your IP as in <your_ip>:8000 from your browser?

Comment: Yes i can access it on my local computer in chrome browser with <myip>:8000, but not from other computers, it was working fine few days ago (even 1 Month it remained in working) but not today.

Comment: that would mean your site is exposed to the local network, and the IP is correct (assuming you have made no changes in HOSTS file). Have you done a ping test between your machine and the other system on the local network?

Comment: Yes i have ping as well the packets are sent and received correctly. Even i have another dashboard made in plotly that is also not accessible from other computers (give that setting of host =0.0.0.0).

Comment: @shoaib30 Problem fixed, But its highly non-deterministic. I had ran the Plotly dashboard and Django dashboard at a time (on different ports) with debug =False and host='0.0.0.0'. When i have stopped the plotly the other dashboard get accessible to other computers. So later after few minutes i ran plotly dashboard . And then checked again both were working find and accessible from other computers. I dont know what is happening under the hood. Totally non deterministic behavior.

Comment: that's weird, but seems like its now  Django issue. could be a firewall or a network level issue. Anyways glad its solved

Comment: Your IP is NOT exposed to the local network.  Two PCs on same network can be running Django applications on 127.0.0.1:8000 because they are running it locally.  You will need to run it using Apache or Nginx

Comment: Nice suggestion, as this is development server so NGINX (Reverse Proxy Server) and GUINICORN (WSGI) could behave exceptionally well in my case to avoid such exceptions, but I have not seen such problem reported anywhere on even the forums. Thats why i have put this questions so that community could get the benefit. Thank you